# How do I enable code formatting for JSON in Zend Studio?

Tags: json, zend-studio

I would like to enjoy code formatting for .json files in Zend Studio. I have tried associating the .json extension with the JavaScript editor, but this has no effect, and Ctrl+Shift+F simply does nothing.

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the file types in "Content Types" as well as in "File Associations", as in:
https://support.zend.com/hc/en-us/articles/203838106-How-to-Add-File-Types-to-the-PHP-Editor